# Updated app version not appearing in BlackBerry AppWorld

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-world

My problem is that on a Blackberry device, in Appworld, my app is showing the old version but when I open Appworld on my PC it shows the new version - with all change requests reflected. What can I do so that people get the newer version for their devices?

I uploaded my app to AppWorld 5 days ago, which also included some changes to the description. Everything was approved.

I have two versions of the app, one for BlackBerry OS pre-5.0 and the other for BlackBerry OS 5.0 and later. But I made a mistake. While selecting the minimum OS version and supported devices for BlackBerry OS pre-5.0, I selected all the devices. I think this is causing my problem. I have since changed the selection of devices for BlackBerry OS pre-5.0. I selected some devices for BlackBerry OS 5.0+, and the other devices I selected for BlackBerry OS pre-5.0.

Comment: Level up version as well. Or resubmit same app with upper version

Comment: @EugenMartynov i am resubmitting the app with upper version.